# What system colour property do Windows tooltips use for their background colour by default?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've got a window I popup that I'd like to style the same as the default Windows tooltip.

What system colour should I be setting the `BackColor` property to? There isn't a `TooltipBackColor` in the system colours property tab.

Apologies to [Jalal Aldeen Saa'd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803668/what-system-colour-property-do-windows-tooltips-use-for-their-background-colour-b/6803698#6803698) but I'm already using `System.Drawing.SystemColors.Info` and this doesn't change from the default dull yellow colour when I change theme, but the tooltip backgrounds do, as you can see in this screen shot:

[image: tooltip colours]

*(It's actually a bug that you can get both the tooltip and the popup visible at the same time)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The windows default is called Info...

EDIT:

If you are in WPF (which supports theming) then according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.systemcolors.infocolor%28v=vs.85%29.aspx it is `System.Windows.SystemColors.InfoColor`
this updates automatically with the chosen theme

**EDIT 2- for WinForms:**
it is a bit more complicated... you instanciate a `System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer` with a `VisualStyleElement.ToolTip.Standard.Normal` and then you can call GetColor on the renderer with `System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.ColorProperty.FillColor`
that gives you the current theme backgoundcolor of a tooltip

Comment: This particular version is WinForms.

Comment: Not quite as simple as this - but you put me on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Drawing.SystemColors.Info
```

You can get it by `new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip().BackColor`

Comment: I should have added that I've tried that to the question, sorry. On XP it worked but on 7 tootips use a different colour that changes with the theme.

Comment: I don't have windows 7 installed but I think `new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip().BackColor` will always return the color used..

Comment: Tried that - didn't have any effect.